# checking if the date the article was posted is less than three days

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to write an if statement checking to see if the artical was updated in the last three days so I can feature it. I'm having a bit of trouble finding out just how to do this though. The more I read in articals, the more it strays from what I need.

So far I have been working with this and it seems to pull back everything that was posted before that moment. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```
if( strtotime($row->update_date) < strtotime('now')){
    print('true');
}?>
```

Comment: You should read http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date-diff.php

Comment: @Alexandre thank you for the link. That's what I read in the first place that kind of confused me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you there

```
if( strtotime($row->update_date) > strtotime('-3 days')){
    print('true');
}
```

Comment: aw that makes scene! I didn't know you could do that with strtotime! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The condition is reversed; this will yield true when the last update was older than three days.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column using SQL as well, assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT ..., update_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAYS) AS less_than_three_days_ago
```

Then, in PHP:

```
if ($row->less_than_three_days_ago) {
    print 'true';
}
```